# How can I pack images? -Pygame -PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I got `main.py` which I turn into `main.exe` through PyInstaller `--onefile`, but `main.exe` still needs image file `img.png` in `\data` folder which is located in same folder as `main.py/main.exe`...

```
img_l = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data', 'img.png'))
screen.blit(img_l, (0, 0))
```

How can I pack these images correctly? I've been messing around for a while now with `pygame.image.tostring` and then trying to save that into `.txt` file so I can use that `.txt` file in `data` folder instead of `img.png`, from which then I could use `pygame.image.fromstring` (maybe) but I have not figured out how to make it work.

I am not even sure if it is the right/ok way to go about it.

Any ideas/suggestions *sincerely* appreciated.

Comment: Turn the images into hex bytearrays or lists, include them in a python file or the actual game file and turn them into binary data when needed?

Comment: I've tried that as well, found some examples but for some reason `from PIL import Image` gets `import error: no module named PIL`. . :/

Comment: You don't need `PIL` for this. Reading and writing in binary mode will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the `fromstring` and `tostring` methods but you could always include 
the images as base64 data. Pygame seems to need an actual image file and not just a blob 
of binary data so in the example below, I've included 3 small icons as base64 strings that 
get written to files in a sub-folder named "data". The filenames are then passed 
to `pygame.image.load()`.

I tested this code with `pyinstaller --onefile filename.py` and 
it worked fine without any manual changes to settings/specs/paths etc.

```
import os
import hashlib
import pygame
import time
import base64

def create_assets(asset_dict, asset_dir):

    """ 
    hand this function a dictionary of assets (images, mp3s, whatever)
    and an absolute path to the data/asset folder. 
    The function creates the folder and files from the base64 strings
    if they don't exist. If the files exist, an md5 check is run
    instead to ensure integrity 
    """

    first_run = False
    if not os.path.isdir(asset_dir):
        os.mkdir(asset_dir)
        first_run = True
    for label in asset_dict:
        asset = asset_dict[label]
        filename = os.path.join(asset_dir, asset["filename"])
        rewrite = False
        # no need to check file if we just created the data folder
        if not first_run:
            if not os.path.isfile(filename):
                # the file doesn't exist
                rewrite = True
            else:
                # file exists - make sure it's intact via md5
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    if not hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest() == asset["md5"]:
                        # the filename exists but the contents is wrong
                        rewrite = True
        if first_run or rewrite:
            # one of our checks failed or first run - write file
            print ("Writing file: ",filename)
            with open(filename, "wb") as f:
                f.write(base64.b64decode(asset["data"]))
        else:
            print ("File exists: ",filename)


""" 
This the data dictionary. It's very easy to save 
the whole thing as json should you feel like it.
The images are just small, random icons at the moment 

"""

assets = {
    "background": {
        "filename": "bg1.png", 
        "data": "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",
        "md5": "12f7eb2eea8992a2644de649dfaf00b3"
        },
    "player_sprite": {
        "filename": "player_img.png", 
        "data": "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",
        "md5": "79f25f0784a7849415f9c3d0d9d05267"
        },
    "weapon": {
        "filename": "sword1.png", 
        "data": "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",
        "md5": "92485d36b8ac414cc758d9a6c6f28d23"
        },
}

# get absolute path to asset directory
asset_dir = "data"
asset_dir_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), asset_dir)

# create files in asset directory using the assets dictionary
create_assets(assets, asset_dir_path)

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

loaded_images = {}

# initalize/load all the newly created images
for label in assets:
    file_path = os.path.join(asset_dir_path,assets[label]["filename"])
    loaded_images[label] = pygame.image.load(file_path)

pos1 = 0
pos2 = 0
t_start = time.time()

while time.time() - t_start < 5:
    for img in loaded_images:
        SCREEN.blit(loaded_images[img], (pos1, pos2))
        time.sleep(0.2)
        pos1 += 20
        pos2 += 20
        pygame.display.update()
```

I turned the images into base64 strings like so:

```
import base64

with open(img_input, "rb") as f:
    with open(img_output_b64, "wb") as f2:
        f2.write(base64.b64encode(f.read()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this is answer to my problem, seems like it :) I am not right now in place to test it, but once I have done that I'll come back and pick this as correct answer (or ask some question if something goes wrong) ^_^

Comment: Yeah, it worked well and smoothly :) **cheers!** Here, have a 'correct answer' (gives you rep I presume?).

Comment: @EsaT.H. Yes, fake internet points all around! :) You get some as well, right? Anyway, thanks. Glad it worked.

Comment: Heh, just thought it would be rude to just run with whatever help ya get without giving anything back, even if it were just some internet points ¯_(ツ)_/¯ thanks again and have a good one! ^_^

Comment: Nice attitude - and emoticon/smiley use! You're welcome

Comment: Sorry I've come up with a question a bit late: how can you save into `data` folder the `img.png` you got from `b64`, and if there is no `data` folder in same place as `main.exe/main.py` create one? Just to keep things tidy :-)

Comment: @EsaT.H. I had an answer ready in case you'd ask that but didn't know if other users would complain if I just gave you the code. I thought your project was interesting so I wrote it for fun. Anyway, if anyone asks, you're not doing homework :D

Comment: *Whoa!* **Cheers!** :D homework? Nah, not student or anything if thats what ya mean. Just trying to learn Python on freetime :)

Comment: @EsaT.H. Cool, it didn't seem like homework either. I'm doing the same btw. - just trying to learn/improve on my own and SO is a good way of doing that while helping people in the process. Anyway, hope the code is useful. Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Comment: Hey guys - just stumbled on this a few days after I created a library that i'm calling [`stringify`](https://github.com/slightlynybbled/stringify) that does nearly the same thing.  I'm using it so that PyInstaller recognizes images as native python code when building a package, but there are clearly lots of uses for this.  Cool concept!