# Fatal error -1 after convert py script to exe (GUI tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I have problem with converting my python script to exe file. I use pyinstaller.

This fatal error occurs, when i try to launch exe file.

I tried different configuration of flags:

> --windowed
>   --noconsole 
>   --onefile
>   --noupx

but it didn't solve problem.

This is only part of my script (GUI):

```
#GUI
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("SAPC - Scanned Aerial Photographs Correction")
window.geometry("300x300+500+200")  
window.iconbitmap(default='favicon.ico')
logo1=PIL.Image.open("logo.png")
logo2 = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo1)
tkinter.Label(window, text="Ver.1.0 Beta")
tkinter.Label(window,image=logo2).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.E+tkinter.S+tkinter.W)

menubar=tkinter.Menu(window)
filemenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openfile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.quit)

editmenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Template selection", command=lambda:      mainfunction())
editmenu.add_command(label="Marker measurement", command=lambda:      pomiarznaczka())
editmenu.add_command(label="Matching", command=lambda: testbutton())
editmenu.add_command(label="Accuracy analysis", command=lambda: analizadok())
editmenu.add_command(label="Transform", command=lambda: transformacja())
editmenu.add_command(label="Mask generator", command=lambda:   maskgenerator())


menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Workflow", menu=editmenu)

window.config(menu=menubar)
window.mainloop()
```

And now when i deleted part of code with loading icon and logo from files and again convert py script to exe file... it works fine.

How i solve this problem? Icon and logo are necessary.

Comment: What if you convert the images to base64 strings and include them in the script? Any change?

Comment: i don't know, how i should do this. You see that i have icon in .ico format and logo in .png format

Comment: I see. Formats don't matter when we're talking base64; it's just a way to convert bytes, ones and zeros, to a string using an extended alphabet (that'll minimize the length of the string). *"(...)  how i should do this"*? I gave [an answer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36720468/6004486) the other day

Comment: Do you recommend any library to convert the images to base64 strings?

Comment: `import base64` :)

Comment: If the other answer doesn't help, you can share a link to one of the images and I'll write a short demo as an answer

Comment: Could you explain me something? In other script i should load these images and convert to base64, using base64 library. Results of this conversion I should use in my main script. Thanks to this solution, i will avoid loading images in their original format?

Comment: You encode your images to base 64 strings outside the script. You include these strings in your script along with their file names (I used a dictionary in the other answer to hold the base64 strings, the file names and an md5 sum to ensure data integrity later on). In the script you've posed here, you decode the strings and write the data to a file again. It'll preserve all the data and the file names (unless you want to change them, of course); nothing is lost in the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the script can't find the image files and fails because there's no code to handle this exception.

I would include the images in the script itself or in a separate python file that you import in the main script. That way you can control the paths and it also eliminates the need for bundling images along with your exe file. Check out [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36720468/6004486) for a full demo of this approach.

The gist of it...

**1** - Convert the images to base64 strings

```
import base64

with open(img_input, "rb") as f:
    with open(img_output_b64, "wb") as f2:
        f2.write(base64.b64encode(f.read()))
```

**2** - Paste the contents of the newly written file, `img_output_b64`, into the main script you've posted here; maybe in a dictionary that also holds the file name and a hash of the original image (so you can ensure integrity later on). Decode and write the image to a file again.

```
import base64

with open(original_image_filename, "wb") as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(image_encoded_as_base64))
```

**3** - Now, you should be able to load it like you're doing in the script you've posted here.

```
window.iconbitmap(default=original_image_filename)
```